# unable to extract value using ._find

Tags: json, node.js, lodash

I have the following node.js code where I want to extract the value "abc" chosen by user as a name. I get result as undefined when I run this code:

```js
let input= [
  {
    "param": [
      {
        "id": "name",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "abc",
            "value": "abc",
            "valueId": "abc"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "alias",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "dsf",
            "value": "dsf",
            "valueId": "dsf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "description",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "",
            "value": "",
            "valueId": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "Key",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "K",
            "value": "K",
            "valueId": "K"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "tagKey",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "",
            "value": "",
            "valueId": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "tagValue",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "",
            "value": "",
            "valueId": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "multiquantity",
        "choice": [
          {
            "label": "1",
            "valueId": "1",
            "value": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "old": [],
    "current": null
  }
]

let result = (_.find(input.param, {id: "name"})).choice[0].valueId;
console.log("value"+result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Seems that the logic is not able to extract the correct value. I need the output as abc. please help

Comment: `input` is Array, try with index `input[0].param` - `let var = (_.find(input[0].param, {id: "name"})).choice[0].valueId;`. `input.param` is undefined in your example

Comment: @Lemix: It did return the value, but it also returns undefined, any idea?

Comment: @FellowBeginner Please update your question with the latest code you are using. The example code what Lemix posted can only return a single value, so "it also returns undefined" doesn't make sense